# Troubleshooting event 5393 from Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-cluster

A Windows Server 2016 cluster is somewhat regularly registering the following event:

> EventID: 5393
> EventLevel: Information
> EventSource: Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering
> MachineName: xxxx
> Message: The Cluster detected that this node is slower than others and degrade Cluster performance. If the condition persists, check for hardware or software errors related to this node. To avoid repeated events it is supress for 24 hours unless the Cluster service is restarted.

We have been unable to determine any significant difference between the cluster nodes that might lead to some performance difference and a search has so far lead to no additional information. Any definitive information regarding what is being tested that leads to this event would be very much appreciated.